# Decryption fails on chaging the IV in AES algorithm

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I have some encoded value received by my webservice. Now I have to decode this encoded string and get the bytes of it.

Now I am using this byte array as my IV value for decrypting a values using AES algorithm. But it is not giving me the proper output rather throws some junk values.

Here is my code,

```
    byte[] decoded =  Base64.decodeBase64(((String) "MTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nw==").getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(decoded, "UTF-8") + "\n");
```

**MTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nw==** is the encoded string received from the request xml.

Now decoded will be IV for the next number to be decrypted,

```
    String c = decrypt1("JHIlf4iXM53tgsKHQEv1dlsUTeLr5GP3LfSNGlWENkg=", decoded);
    System.out.println(c);
```

**JHIlf4iXM53tgsKHQEv1dlsUTeLr5GP3LfSNGlWENkg=** is the digit to be decrypted.

```
      public static String decrypt1(Object data, byte[] ivBytes) throws InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            byte[] keyBytes = "keyPhrase".getBytes();
            Cipher cipher = null;
            if (ivBytes.length<16) {
                System.out.println("error" + ivBytes.length); 
                //ivBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 97, 98, 99,  100, 101, 102, 103};
            }
        byte[] byteArr = null;
       try {
          SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
          cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(
                ivBytes));
           if (data instanceof String) {
            byteArr = Base64.decodeBase64(((String) data).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } 
        byteArr = (cipher.doFinal(byteArr));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return byteArr;
     return new String(byteArr);
}
```

**Note:**

Instead if I use this IV,

```
 byte[] ivBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0};  it works as expected.
```

Comment: Can you post your encryption code where you generate the IV?  The IV needs to be the same for encryption and decryption

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're storing the IV alongside the ciphertext so you can read and use it during decryption.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, Yes what you told is correct. I was using a different IV to encrypt JHIlf4iXM53tgsKHQEv1dlsUTeLr5GP3LfSNGlWENkg=. If I use same IV's it works fine. Thanks for your answer. If you can post this as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same initialization vector for encryption and decryption; you can transmit the IV in plaintext (i.e. it isn't secret)

You should also use a different IV for each ciphertext, generated with e.g. a counter or with [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)